# Set dataset observation names to first column

Tags: matlab

I am trying to set the first column of my dataset as the observation name. Each observation is a separate stock within dataset 'portfolio'.

I tried this command:

```
portfolio.Properties.ObsNames = portfolio.ticker
```

I got the error message

```
Error using dataset/subsasgnDot (line 31)
NEWNAMES must be a nonempty string or a cell array of nonempty strings.

Error in dataset/subsasgn (line 83)
a = subsasgnDot(a,s,b);
```

I looked at the code but didn't see where I went wrong.

I tried casting to a cell array but it didn't work. I used this code:

```
portfolio.Properties.ObsNames = dataset2cell(portfolio.ticker)
```

and got this error message

```
Undefined function 'dataset2cell' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

What should I try next?

Comment: For the second part of your question, won't {portfolio.ticker(:)} do the cast?

Comment: That gives me the error message "NEWNAMES must contain one name for each observation in A."

Answer (score 0):

I managed to cast it by doing the cast on a separate line.

Comment: I would recommend you to include the relevant code and later accept your answer so the question won't remain unanswered.